# How to add the original close button inside iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I use jQuery modal window plugin: [iziModal](http://izimodal.marcelodolce.com).
I have already implemented iFrame that comes out when I click on a specific place.

---

### What I want to do

When iFrame is open, I want a close button.
But I want to make the original close button. Like this:
[image: this]

---

### Code

jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '.item1', function (event) {
  $(".item1").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#iframe").iziModal('open');
    $('#modal').iziModal('open', {
      iframeURL: $(this).data('href')
    });
  });
  $("#modal").iziModal({
    iframe: true,
    width: '98%',
    iframeHeight: 650,
    zindex: '110',
    iframeURL: "data.html",
    group: 'works',
    overlayColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
    closeButton: false
  });
  $(".item1").off('click');
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/ejncvz2k/2/)

---

### What I tried

```
$(document).on('opened', '#modal', function(clsbtn) {
  var clsbtn = $('<button>').addClass('clsbtn');
  $(this).before(clsbtn);
})
```

If I close the iFrame, it will be displayed forever.
In addition, this will create a button outside the iFrame.

Comment: `addclass` would be `addClass`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Ah! Thank you very much.
However, I still can not add the original close button..

Comment: Doubt you want `before()` and probably want `prepend()` so button is inside `#modal`

Comment: @charlietfl It's true! When I checked it with color, it was properly added before `#modal`.
But even after closing iFrame, it remains forever and does not disappear..

Comment: @POP your options for the plugin has this: `closeButton: false` change that to `true`

Comment: @zer00ne It didn't work..

Comment: @POP It works now see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55352160/2813224)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things needed for a close button:

#### [option: `closeButton: true`](http://izimodal.marcelodolce.com/#Options)

This option by default is `true`...in the OP (**O**riginal **P**ost) it is explicitly set to `false`....?

> ```
>  $("#modal").iziModal({
>     iframe: true,
>     width: '98%',
>     iframeHeight: 300,
>     zindex: '110',
>     iframeURL: "https://css-tricks.com/",
>     group: 'works',
>     overlayColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
>     closeButton: true //========== closeButton ======================| ADDED |
>     ...
> ```

---

#### [HTML: Button Needs to be in the Modal](http://izimodal.marcelodolce.com/#DataAttributes)

> ```
> <div id="modal">
>   <button data-izimodal-close="">Close</button> <!========| ADDED |=====-->
>  </div>
> ```

---

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/n0bpots1/)

### Demo

```js
/* iziModal */
$(document).on('click', '.item1', function(event) {
  $(".item1").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#iframe').iziModal('open');
    $('#modal').iziModal('open', {
      iframeURL: $(this).data('href')
    });
  });
  $("#modal").iziModal({
    iframe: true,
    width: '98%',
    iframeHeight: 300,
    zindex: '110',
    iframeURL: "https://css-tricks.com/",
    group: 'works',
    overlayColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
    closeButton: true //====================| ADDED |
  });
  $(".item1").off('click');
});
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

#items {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 3.8rem 4.6rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(170px, 1fr));
}

.item {
  text-align: center;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.item h2 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin-top: 1.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.item p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
}

.item h2,
.item p {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izimodal/1.5.1/css/iziModal.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<!-- Please click on the title1 section. iFrame opens. -->
<div class="list">
  <div id="items">
    <section class="item item1" data-izimodal-iframeurl="https://css-tricks.com/" data-izimodal-open=#modal data-href="/iframe_url1">
      <img src="https://placehold.jp/1219a3/1219a3/170x120.png" alt="1" />
      <h2>title1</h2>
      <p>description1 description1</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item item2" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-2.html" data-izimodal-open=#modal data-href="/iframe_url2">
      <img src="https://placehold.jp/1219a3/1219a3/170x120.png" alt="2" />
      <h2>title2</h2>
      <p>description2 description2</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item item3" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-3.html" data-izimodal-open=#modal data-href="/iframe_url3">
      <img src="https://placehold.jp/1219a3/1219a3/170x120.png" alt="3" />
      <h2>title3</h2>
      <p>description3 description3</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item item4" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-4.html" data-izimodal-open=#modal data-href="/iframe_url4">
      <img src="https://placehold.jp/1219a3/1219a3/170x120.png" alt="4" />
      <h2>title4</h2>
      <p>description4 description4</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item item5" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-5.html" data-izimodal-open=#modal data-href="/iframe_url5">
      <img src="https://placehold.jp/1219a3/1219a3/170x120.png" alt="5" />
      <h2>title5</h2>
      <p>description5 description5</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="modal">
  <!--========================================| ADDED |-->
  <button data-izimodal-close="">Close</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izimodal/1.5.1/js/iziModal.js'></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
For now, the close button is displayed before opening the first modal, but is there any measure for this?
And I want to make the close button appear "by hover", but it doesn't work. How should I do?
I feel like this now. -> [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/51pums7t/1/)

Comment: One problem per post. Make your new request on a new post.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you.

Comment: @POP when you post the next question, you can notify me by commenting here. Happy coding.